# How to edit ionic cordova plugin

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to do small changes in the ionic cordova plugin I use. To be specific I use

```
 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation" spec="2.3.6">
```

I do NOT want to install new version of this plugin and I do NOT have issues with this plugin.

Everything is fine, I just want to do my own small changes. I found these 3 files, which are the same:

```
Mobile-App\node_modules\cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation\android\plugin\src\main\java\com\marianhello\bgloc\LocationService.java
Mobile-App\platforms\android\src\com\marianhello\bgloc\LocationService.java
Mobile-App\plugins\cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation\android\plugin\src\main\java\com\marianhello\bgloc\LocationService.java
```

I want to edit method public int onStartCommand() which is (again) in all 3 files.

**Question: Which file should I edit?**

Why there are the same file multiple times?

And will be changes applied immediately or I need to recompile the plugin?

I do not want to create new version and install/uninstall stuff can I just modify the file and recompile the app?

Comment: You might need to edit the corresponding plugin in the plugins folder and after that, you can generate the platform which contains the plugins you edited. You need to edit every time if you git clone again because the plugins folder is not pushed by git which is ignored in gitignore. So my advice you can just fork the plugin and edit there, and using the plugin that you have fork in your ionic project

Comment: OK, I will try that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ended by editing all 3 files - they are exactly the same so I edit the file once and copy the same content everywhere.

Comment: Note: the plugin .java files are compiled when the apk file is build (from Gradle) so there is no need to compile them extra.